# Dockerfile immediately stopping after use of docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mariadb, alpine-linux

I have a problem regarding one of my Dockerfile, indeed once the image is built it immediately stops after being run with the `docker run` command, my Dockerfile base image is alpine:3.18 and I run Mariadb inside the container.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.18

ARG APP_USER=mysql

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache mariadb mariadb-client

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/${APP_USER}

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld && \
    chown -R ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /var/run/mysqld && \
    chmod -R 750 /var/run/mysqld

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/${APP_USER} && \
    chown -R ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /var/lib/${APP_USER} && \
    chmod -R 750 /var/lib/${APP_USER} && \
    mkdir -p /var/run/${APP_USER} && \
    chown -R ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /var/run/${APP_USER} && \
    chmod -R 750 /var/run/${APP_USER} && \
    chown -R ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /var/log/${APP_USER} && \
    chmod -R 750 /var/log/${APP_USER}

COPY ./conf/my.cnf /etc/${APP_USER}/my.cnf

COPY ./tools/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

EXPOSE 3306

USER ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER}

CMD ["mysqld_safe"]
```

Here is the `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

# Security
skip-networking
```

Here is the script that will create an admin user and set a password for the root user:

```
CREATE USER ${ADMIN_USERNAME}@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ${ADMIN_PASSWORD};
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${MARIADB_DB_NAME}.* TO ${ADMIN_USERNAME}@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ${ADMIN_PASSWORD};
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ${ROOT_PASSWORD};
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

CREATE DATABASE wordpress;
```

I checked the exit status of my container, and the status is 0 it seems that all is OK but my container stops immediately when started using `docker run` command.

Here is the used command:

```
sudo docker run -d --name mariadb-container -p 3000:3306 mariadb-try:v1
```

And here are the dockers logs:

```
230611 19:52:59 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
230611 19:52:59 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Could you add to this question: (a) the `docker run` command you are using, and (b) the docker logs produced? If you are using `-d` to detach the console output, drop that for the purposes of collecting runtime logs.

Comment: Why not use the mariadb docker image? It likely has an entrypoint script that solves this stuff already.

Comment: this is a school homework I can't use mariadb images, @halfer I added what you asked

Comment: OK, there are no error logs there - worth checking though. Try adding `--mysqld-version=debug` to `mysqld_safe`, [per the instructions here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-safe.html). Maybe that will produce more log lines, so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can run and attach a console to the container and from there launch the `mysqld_safe`.

### Run

This command attaches a sh console to the container, preventing it from exiting (this does not solve your problem...)

`docker run -it -d --name mariadb-container --rm -p 3000:3306 mariadb-try:v1 sh`

### Attach

This attaches another *interactive* console, from there you are on the system and you can explore it.

`docker exec -it mariadb-container sh`

### Start MariaDB

From within the container console run
`mysqld_safe`

This produces the same output you have in your question

```
230612 15:01:43 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
230612 15:01:43 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

### Investigate

Now you can read the error log from `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.4-MariaDB source revision 4e2b93dffef2414a11ca5edc8d215f57ee5010e5 as process 95
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first data file './ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /var/tmp (disabling future attempts)
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibdata1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibdata1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=512 bytes)
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 0; transaction id 3
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist
2023-06-12 15:01:44 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Warning: Memory not freed: 280
```

### Correct

Now you have the **true** error, you can solve the error(s) inside the machine, without rebuilding the image (and note the required step to replicate on Dockerfile) and retry to start the MySQL.